# PHP get database data in input field

Tags: php

I have exmple , that i want to change. I get data from database and in example, their ar shown like this

```
$display_string .= "<td>$row[name]</td>";
```

But i need them in input box, what i later can edit in my web and send data back to database.
I try something like this:

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\"".$row['name']."\"></input>
```

But it is not working. I try something like this, with another syntax too, but nothing. Can any body help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
echo "<input type='text' name='name' value='".$row['name']."'>";
```

Also you dont need closing tag `</input>`

Comment: Yes it work's . Thank you. I am beginner , need to work with my syntax more !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=<?php echo $row['name']; ? />
```